# Remove rows with duplicate values using a macro

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I am trying to remove rows with duplicate values using a macros.

For E.g

1 2 3 4 5 6

1 2 2 4 5 6

1 1 3 5 4 6

7 5 2 3 2 1

5 7 8 5 6 7

I am currently using a filter to pick up if there are any duplicates in the rows.

I would like to remove these rows somehow using a macros as there are way to many rows to do it manually.

Comment: What constitutes a duplicate in your scenario? You just provide the input. What is the expected result? What is the logic? Also, this site is not a free coding service. What code do you have so far? Where are you stuck? Nobody will do it all for you.

Answer (score 0):

From Excel's Help.

**Filter for unique records**

- Select the column or click a cell in the list you want to filter.  On
  the Data menu, point to Filter, and then click Advanced Filter.

Do one of the following.

- To filter the list in place, similar to using AutoFilter, click
  Filter the list, in-place.
- To copy the results of the filter to
  another location, click Copy to another location. Then, in the Copy
  To box, enter a cell reference.   To select a cell, click Collapse
  Dialog  to temporarily hide the dialog box. Select the cell on the
  worksheet, and then press Expand Dialog .

Select the Unique records only check box.

If you want it in a macro record it. **Alt + T, M, R**